# CentOS 7 Forward port to another IP:PORT

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, bash

I have CentOS 7 that uses IPTABLES for Forwarding port 30120 to windows server

For example :
Windows games server IP: 192.168.1.3
Linux Centos 7 server IP : 192.168.1.5

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30120 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:30120

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.3 --dport 30120 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.5

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 30120 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:30120

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -d 192.168.1.3 --dport 30120 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.5
```

and I have rules to anti DDOS and secure SSH but it's not work with forward
still forwarding traffic from my Centos to 192.168.1.3:30120

My PC IP: 192.168.1.2
Have used for test in CentOS

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.2 -j DROP
```

This IP 192.168.1.2 can't access to CentOS 7 but can forwarding to windows server by port 30120

How it's blocked?

thank you.

Comment: In CentOS 7, you probably should be using `firewall-cmd` instead of `iptables`

Comment: In reference to @fpmurphy, at least you ought to make sure that you have firewalld disabled, stopped and masked and the iptables service started or else firewalld will overwrite your iptables rules.
Firewalld is the default frontend to iptables in centos7. It will not tolerate you adding iptables rules by yourself unless disabled.

Answer (score -1):

The order of the rules matters, so if the port forwarding rules are before the DROP rule, those take precedence and only other traffic is dropped. If you want to drop all traffic, move the DROP line above the port forwarding lines.

Comment: They aren't even in the same chain.

Answer (score -1):

The general syntax is:

```
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=port-number:proto=tcp|udp:toport=port-number:toaddr=IP/mask

firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
```

Case-specific example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=30120:proto=tcp:toport=30120:toaddr=192.168.1.100
  --permanent
```